# Moment.js how to use fromNow() to return everything in hours?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I've searching the [moment.js docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/) and [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) for a way to use the `fromNow()` function but returning everything in hours.

What I mean is:

```
moment([2017, 01, 05]).fromNow();     // a day ago
```

should be

```
moment([2017, 01, 05]).fromNow();     // 24 hours ago
```

I know it's possible to do this using `.diff` and probably other similar functions and then adding the text, but is it possible to use `.fromNow()` to do this?

Comment: Did you ask this earlier and delete it?

Comment: Nope, first time asking it, why?

Comment: Someone posted a question with a **very** similar title earlier today, which I can't now find.

Comment: I would also like to see it as it may solve my question.

Comment: That's why I went looking for it. :-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use [`relativeTimeThreshold`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/customization/relative-time-threshold/) to customize thresholds for moment relative time.

As the docs says:

> `duration.humanize` has thresholds which define when a unit is considered a minute, an hour and so on. For example, by default more than 45 seconds is considered a minute, more than 22 hours is considered a day and so on. To change those cutoffs use `moment.relativeTimeThreshold(unit, limit)` where unit is one of `s`, `m`, `h`, `d`, `M`.

In your case, you can increase hour thresholds to get relative days as hours. Here a working example showing time as hours from 1 hour to 26 days:

```js
var m1 = moment().subtract(5, 'h');
var m2 = moment().subtract(55, 'h');
var m3 = moment().subtract(1, 'd');

// Default results
console.log(m1.fromNow());
console.log(m2.fromNow());
console.log(m3.fromNow());

// Change relativeTimeThreshold
moment.relativeTimeThreshold('m', 60);
moment.relativeTimeThreshold('h', 24*26);

// Results in hours
console.log(m1.fromNow());
console.log(m2.fromNow());
console.log(m3.fromNow());
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Note that, if you need, moment lets you customize relative time further with [`relativeTime`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/customization/relative-time/) ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38385371/4131048) one of my examples) and [`relativeTimeRounding`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/customization/relative-time-rounding/) method.

Answer (score 4):

If you definitely want to use `fromNow()`, I don't see any way other than overriding moment's built-in function. For example, you can override it to return the difference in hours as follows:

```
moment.fn.fromNow = function (a) {
    var duration = moment().diff(this, 'hours');
    return duration;
}
```

Then you can check that `fromNow()` returns the value in hours:

```
console.log(moment([2017,0,6]).fromNow());
```

which returns:

```
19
```

Note: Tried at 19:00 :)

Comment: what may return 1year, 2months, and 5seconds?