# difference in minute between to date

Tags: date, momentjs

I receive a beginning date for a live sport event and i want to calculate the minutes between this date and now, so i tried this with moment :

```
function(dateofevent) {
   var locale = window.navigator.userLanguage || window.navigator.language;
   var diff = moment(dateofevent).locale(locale).fromNow(true);
   return diff;
}
```

In a sense it works because it shows for example "12 minuts ago" or "2 hours ago" but i want a result only in minuts (128' for example). Is there a way to do that with moment ?

Comment: Maybe a dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224834/get-difference-between-2-dates-in-javascript

Comment: not really because i doesn't use moment

Comment: I'm just mentioning it, because is "in 300 minutes" really preferable to "in 5 hours"?

Comment: yes because i have no space where i want to display it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Moment.js how to use fromNow() to return everything in hours?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41508796/moment-js-how-to-use-fromnow-to-return-everything-in-hours)