# moment js end of from now return only in hours

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Does someone know how can I get in hours not days, this code below returns 3 days, I would like to return 72 hours

```js
console.log(moment("2022-04-14T09:07:08.086Z").endOf('hours').fromNow(true))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: If you're going to add a snippet to the question, please make sure it works! If it's not meant to be runnable then don't use snippets

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Moment.js how to use fromNow() to return everything in hours?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41508796/moment-js-how-to-use-fromnow-to-return-everything-in-hours)
As a side note - momentjs is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const toHours = (days) => { days = days.substring(0, days.indexOf(' '))
                          return 24*days
}

console.log(toHours(moment("2022-04-14T09:07:08.086Z").fromNow(true)))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

OR use relative threshold by moment (sometimes incorrect due to rounding off)

```js
moment.relativeTimeThreshold('h', 24*26);

console.log(moment("2022-04-14T09:07:08.086Z").endOf('hours').fromNow(true))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```