# MomentJs get "time until" with two variables

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am trying to get moment.js to show me time until a specific date.  I have that done doing this:

```
let date = 2017-03-27T12:00:00;
moment().to(date);
```

This shows: "`in 10 days`".

I'd really like this to show "`in 10 days and 2 hours`" or the two highest values.  For example, `1 year and 5 months`, `4 minutes and 30 seconds`.

Is there a simple way to do this? I am currently working on a complicated method to handle this...

```
let years = moment(date).local().diff(moment(), 'years');
let months = (moment(date).local().diff(moment(), 'months'));
let days = (moment(date).local().diff(moment(), 'days'));
let hours = (moment(date).local().diff(moment(), 'hours'));
let minutes = (moment(date).local().diff(moment(), 'minutes'));
let seconds = (moment(date).local().diff(moment(), 'seconds'));

//The above values return total number each, 
//For example, this could show 1 year, 14 months, 435 days, etc.
//The math below is supposed to make this say
//1 year, 2 months, 14 days, etc.

let yearsRemain = years;
let monthsRemain = months - (years *12);
let daysRemain = days - (Math.floor(months * 30));
let hoursRemain = hours - (days * 24);
let minutesRemain = minutes - (hours * 60);
let secondsRemain = seconds - (minutes * 60);

var dateArray = [
  yearsRemain,
  monthsRemain,
  daysRemain,
  hoursRemain,
  minutesRemain,
  secondsRemain
]

console.log(dateArray);

/*

returns [1, 1, 3, 23, 16, 46] for example

*/
```

the problem with this is when it comes to days.  Since days in a year and days in a month vary, I was hoping moment.js would help me out.  Is there a better way of doing this?

Eventually, I will be able to iterate through the array and find the two largest values to display how I'd like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`moment.duration`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/) to calculate the `dateArray` value. Duration has [`years()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/years/), [`months()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/months/), [`days()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/days/), [`hours()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/hours/), [`minutes()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/minutes/), [`seconds()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/seconds/) getters.

Here a live example:

```js
let date = '2017-03-27T12:00:00';
var dur = moment.duration( moment(date).diff(moment()) );

let yearsRemain = dur.years();
let monthsRemain = dur.months();
let daysRemain = dur.days();
let hoursRemain = dur.hours();
let minutesRemain = dur.minutes();
let secondsRemain = dur.seconds();

var dateArray = [
  yearsRemain,
  monthsRemain,
  daysRemain,
  hoursRemain,
  minutesRemain,
  secondsRemain
]

console.log(dateArray);
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

You can use [moment-duration-format](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/plugins/duration-format/) plug-in to show duration in a custom format. The plugin has a [`template`](https://github.com/jsmreese/moment-duration-format#template) option that lets you customize the format.

```js
let date = '2017-03-27T12:00:00';
let dur = moment.duration( moment(date).diff(moment()) );
console.log( dur.format() );
console.log( dur.format('M [months and] d [days]') );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-duration-format/1.3.0/moment-duration-format.min.js"></script>
```

Note that moments has [`relativeTime`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/customization/relative-time/), [`relativeTimeRounding`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/customization/relative-time-rounding/) and [`relativeTimeThreshold`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/customization/relative-time-threshold/) that lets you customize how moment shows relative time (so you can change `to` output).

Comment: Thank you, I am technically working in ionic 2 with typescript.  Once I find out how to import the moment-duration-format into my project, I will try this out.  Thank you!

Comment: Your first block of code works like a charm.  You made me realize I should be working off of 1 duration, rather than several.  thank you!