# Replace a few seconds ago with just now in moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs, moment-timezone

How to remove few seconds ago and show **just now** in `moment.js` .The `moment.js` shows a few seconds ago ,I want to do some customization ,to show only just now  upto 1 minute.But in other cases  like two minutes ago I want to show 2 minutes ago.

`Example 0-59 seconds just now`

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import moment from "moment";
export default function App() {
  moment.updateLocale("en", {
    relativeTime: {
      future: "in %s",
      past: "%s ago",
      s: " %ds",
      ss: "%d seconds",
      m: "%dm",
      mm: "%dm",
      h: "an h",
      hh: "%dh",
      d: "a day",
      dd: "%d days",
      w: "a week",
      ww: "%d weeks",
      M: "a month",
      MM: "%d months",
      y: "a year",
      yy: "%d years"
    }
  });
  const MINUTE_MS = 60000;

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      console.log("Logs every minute");
      called();
    }, MINUTE_MS);

    return () => clearInterval(interval); // This represents the unmount function, in which you need to clear your interval to prevent memory leaks.
  }, []);
  const called = () => {
    var k = Date.now() - 5 * 1000;
    return k;
  };
  moment.locale("en");

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>{moment(called()).fromNow()}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Please add some code of what you've tried.

Comment: maki00: I have updated

Comment: I don't think you can play with those values (2 minutes instead of 1 minute). Your best shot is to implement a similar one. Check https://github.com/moment/moment/blob/develop/src/lib/duration/humanize.js

Comment: alpakyol: my question is , moment.js showing a few seconds ago I want replace this with just now..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Format relative time in momentJs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38367038/format-relative-time-in-momentjs)

Comment: Lucifer: The answer is here,but I don't know how to use it my case
https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/537

Answer (score 0):

You could set `s` and `ss` to `"just now"` and change both `future` and `past` into a function that doesn't prefix/suffix if the passed string is `"just now"`.

```js
moment.updateLocale("en", {
  relativeTime: {
    future: (diff) => (diff == "just now" ? diff : `in ${diff}`),
    past: (diff) => (diff == "just now" ? diff : `${diff} ago`),
    s: "just now",
    ss: "just now"
  }
});

const _2_min_ago = moment().subtract(2, "minutes");
const _20_sec_ago = moment().subtract(20, "seconds");
const _20_sec_from_now = moment().add(20, "seconds");
const _2_min_from_now = moment().add(2, "minutes");

console.log(_2_min_ago.fromNow());
console.log(_20_sec_ago.fromNow());
console.log(_20_sec_from_now.fromNow());
console.log(_2_min_from_now.fromNow());
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```